# how to login with encrypted password at wso2is 5.8v

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Currently we are using wso2is v5.8 in our product to authenticate the user from AD/LDAP.

At the time of login, we sending login form data in simple text format and it's working as expected but due to vulnerability we have an issue, we want to post-login form data password field as an encrypted format. how I will achieve that pls help me with that. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: `want to post-login form data password field as an encrypted format` that's what **HTTPS** is for

Answer (score 1):

In WSO2IS from user store managers, passwords can be encrypted so no need to send encrypted passwords from the Login page or Registration page.

**1. Encrypt passwords in primary user-store manager**
Go to ***< IS-HOME >/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml*** file and then in there uncomment the below line
`<Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>`
and for the hashing method, you can use

1. SHA - Uses SHA digest method. SHA-1, SHA-256
2. MD5 - Uses MD 5 digest method.
3. PLAIN_TEXT - Plain text passwords.

**2. Encrypt passwords in secondary user-store manager**
In the secondary user-store managers there is an option "PasswordHashMethod" available to configure, if it is not configured it will not do any hashing to the user password.
But in there can specify the Password Hashing Algorithm used the hash the password before storing it in the user store.

Possible values:

1. SHA - Uses SHA digest method. SHA-1, SHA-256
2. MD5 - Uses MD 5 digest method.
3. PLAIN_TEXT - Plain text passwords.

***Note***:
If you just configure it as SHA, it is considered as SHA-1. It is always better to configure an algorithm with a higher bit value as digest bit size would be increased.